# Householder reflection in geometric algebra is not working for me

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-algebras

A Householder reflection  of a vector $v$ along a direction $n$ is
given by the formula
\begin{eqnarray}
  v' = v - 2 \frac{n \cdot v}{|n|^2} n.
\end{eqnarray}

If $n$ is unitary then $v'=v-2 (n \cdot v) n$.
Clearly for $v=(2,3)$ and $n=(0,1)$ we find that $v'=(2,-3)$
which in fact is the Householder reflection of $(2,3)$ along the vector $(0,1)$.

According to Geometric Algebra (GA) a Housholder reflection is defined
as $-nvn^{-1}$. Since $n$ is unitary $n^{-1}=n$ and we can write
$v'=-nvn$. However when I compute this formula with the vectors above, I get different results.

Let me explain:
\begin{eqnarray}
 n v = (0,1) \cdot (2,3) + (0,1) \wedge (2,3) = 3 - 2 e_1 \wedge e_2.
\end{eqnarray}
and so

\begin{eqnarray}
v' = -nvn^{-1} = -(3 -2 e_1 \wedge e_2) n  = -3n + 2 e_1 \wedge e_2 n.
\end{eqnarray}

My concern  is that, since $e_1 \wedge e_2$ is equivalent to a 90
degree counterclockwise rotation then we find that the second (last) term
here is $(-2,0)$ and so the result is $v'=-3(0,1)+2(-1,0)=(-2,-3)$
and not $(2,-3)$ as expected.

Probably I have a stupid error such a sign somewhere or a deep problem on understanding the geometric algebraic product.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is apparently with your interpretation, because the math is working out.
$$ -nvn^{-1} = -(3 -2 e_1 \wedge e_2) n  = -3n + 2 e_1 \wedge e_2 n=-3e_2+2e_1e_2e_2=2e_1-3e_2$$.

I’m not even sure why you were using the product identity with the wedge. You may as well just compute it directly:

$$
-nvn =-e_2(2e_1+3e_2)e_2=-2e_2e_1e_2-3e_2e_2e_2=2e_1-3e_2
$$

It seems to me that multiplication by $e_1\wedge e_2$ on the left creates a *clockwise* rotation by 90, since it maps $e_2$ to $ e_1$ and $e_1$ to $-e_2$.

Comment: So, is it wrong to say that $e_1 e_2 u$ (I get your point. I can remove the wedge symbol here) is a  $\pi/2$ positive rotation on $u$?  I thought $e_1 e_2$ behaved as the imaginary complex number $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Thanks.

Comment: $| e_1 e_2 |^2 = (e_1 e_2)^*(e_1 e_2)= e_2 e_1 e_1 e_2 = 1$ so $e_1 e_2 = \sqrt{-1}$. Right?

Comment: Now the problem reduces to the following: Assuming the associative law is valid: $(e_1 e_2) e_2=-e_1$, $e_1(e_2 e_2)=e_1 1=e_1$.  Why is the first interpratation wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo If you multiply on the right with it, it will send $e_1\to e_2$ and $e_2\to -e_1$. To model complthe x multiplication, you’d have to write numbers with a real part and a complex part using $e_1\wedge e_2$, not as a linear combination of $e_1$ and $e_2$. So I think you are mixing  interpretations.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo $(e_1e_2)e_2=e_1$, not $-e_1$.

Comment: So is it wrong to say that $e_1 e_2$ can be changed for the imaginary unit $i$?

Comment: @HermanJaramillo No, it does not work like $i$ on $\langle e_1, e_2\rangle$. But it *does* work like $i$ on $\langle 1, e_1e_2\rangle$. If you represent $(a,b)\mapsto a+be_1\wedge e_2$, then everything works.

Comment: I believe I understand now. $e_1 e_2$ behaves as the imaginary number $i$ when it is premultiplied by a vector $e_j$, but it behaves as $-i$ when it is post multiplied by a vector $e_j$. This makes sense since the product is anticommutative.  This does not happen in the complex numbers where the product of complex numbers is commutative.  Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo correct. But $\langle 1,e_1e_2\rangle$ is a copy of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: That is correct. Previously I did not understand your notation $\langle, \rangle$ because I was thinking on inner products but you are talking about spanning a space. Now since 1  is a scalar it commutes with $e_1 e_2$, but if instead of 1 you pick a vector $a$ then $\langle a, e_1 e_2 \rangle$ spans a space where only if $e_1 e_2$ is at the right ,  it resembles a counterclockwise rotation on $a$. On the left would be a clockwise rotation. I am thinking on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Here is a related question:  \begin{eqnarray*}
  (e_1 e_2)^2 = e_1 e_2 e_1 e_2 = -e_1 e_1 e_2 e_2 = -1
\end{eqnarray*}
So 


\begin{eqnarray*}
  (e_1 e_2) = \pm \sqrt{-1} = \pm \mathrm{i}.
\end{eqnarray*}   So which sign should I pick for $e_1 e_2$ and why?

Comment: @HermanJaramillo It does not matter. Whichever one you use yields something isomorphic to $\mathbb C$

Comment: This is the point. In that isomorphism we could identify $i$ with $e_2=(0,1)$. If we pick the plus "+" sign then $(e_1 e_2) e_1$ we find $ i e_1 = e_2 e_1$, if instead we pick the "-"sign then $(e_1 e_2) e_1 = -i e_2 = -e_2 e_1$. This is the source of my problems all along.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you have had a revelation on your own!

Comment: I think I understand what is going on now. Let us assume in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that we have the base  $1, e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)$ and $e_1 e_2=\mathrm{i}$. Now let us think of another basis $1, e_1=(1,0)$, $e_2=(0,1)$, $e_1 e_2$. In this case the system is "left handed" and then $e_1 e_2=-\mathrm{i}$. So the plus or minus $\pm$ $\mathrm{i}$ instead of $e_1 e_2$  is used accordingly if the system is left or right handed

Comment: @HermanJaramillo I don’t quite understand why you think the sign has anything to do with handedness. If you take any of the (uncountable many) unit vectors that square to -1 in the quaternions, the span of that vector with $1$ gives a copy of C

Comment: @HermanJaramillo I thought more about it and I think I agree now that choosing the sign on $e_1e_2$ would change the handedness of $\{e_1,e_2,e_1e_2\}$, but I don’t think it changes anything about the copy of $\mathbb C$ generated by $\{1,e_1e_2\}$.